# handler.postDelayed() not executing

Tags: android, sleep, android-handler

I want to display some text after a period of time.

I initially started with Thread.sleep(). It just paused before immediately executing the code.

```
mTextView.setText("3");
try{
    Thread.sleep(500);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mTextView.setText("2");
```

But it would pause for 500 milliseconds and then display "2".
It would never show "3".

So, I switched to a handler.

```
mTextView.setText("3");
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mTextView.setText("2");
    }
}, 500);
```

But for some reason, it jumps to display "2," without pausing. It seems like the handler did not delay.

Why and how do I make it delay?

Comment: Well, a 500ms delay is fairly short, so you might not notice the change, particularly depending upon what else you may be doing.

Comment: Did you try changing the delay to a larger number? If it still is instantly loading you can rule out that problem

Comment: I tried changing it to 5000ms, but it still didn't work.

Comment: in both cases you have an issue with the initial setText("3") - there is nothing wrong with how the handler is set is the code you've submitted. It has to be something/somewhere else in the rest of the code causing the issue. I couldn't replicate your problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
      for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mTextView.setText(""+(i+2));
            }
        }, 500*i);
}
```